# Every batch causes a compile

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

We have a third party application that sends T-SQL statements in batches.

The database is hosted on a SQL Server 2016 Enterprise SP1 CU7, 16 cores and 256GB memory. Optimize for Ad-Hoc is enabled.

This is a dummy example of the queries that are being executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT

select field1, field2 from table1 where field1=@1
option(keep plan, keepfixed, loop join)

select field3, field4 from table2 where field3=@1
option(keep plan, keepfixed, loop join)', N'@1 nvarchar(6)',@1=N'test'
```

When I monitor the database and I look at batches/sec and compiles/sec, I notice they are always the same.  Under heavy load, this can be 1000 batches/sec and 1000 compiles/sec.  Under average load, there are 150 batches/sec.

I analyze the query cache for recently compiled plans:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) qs.creation_time
    , DatabaseName = DB_NAME(st.dbid)
    , qs.execution_count
    , st.text
    , qs.plan_handle
    , qs.sql_handle
    , qs.query_hash 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) AS st
ORDER BY creation_time DESC;
```

When I run above query I only see 10-20 new query plans/sec.

It's like every `sp_executesql` call triggers a compile but the queryplan is not cached.

What can be the cause of batches/sec being equal to compiles/sec ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> It's like every `sp_executesql` call triggers a compile but the query plan is not cached.

SQL Server **does not cache** a query plan for batches containing only an `sp_executesql` call. Without a cached plan, a compilation occurs each time. This is by design, and expected.

SQL Server avoids caching batches with a low cost to compile. The details of what is and is not cached has changed many times over the years. See my answer to [Trace flag 2861 and what a 'zero-cost' plan actually means](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/139659/1192) for details.

In short, the probability of reuse (including specific parameter values) is small, and the cost of compiling the ad hoc text containing the `sp_executesql` call is very small. The inner parameterized batch produced by `sp_executesql` is of course cached and reused - this is the value of it. The extended stored procedure `sp_executesql` itself is also cached.

To be cached and reused, the `sp_executesql` statement would have to be part of a larger batch that is considered worth caching. For example:

```
-- Show compilation counter
SELECT
    DOPC.[object_name],
    DOPC.cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS DOPC
WHERE
    DOPC.counter_name = N'SQL Compilations/sec'
GO
-- This is only here to make the batch worth caching
DECLARE @TC integer =
(
    SELECT TOP (1) @@TRANCOUNT 
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values AS SV
);

-- Example call we are testing
-- (use anything for the inner query, this example uses the Stack Overflow database
EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql 
    N'SELECT LT.Type FROM dbo.LinkTypes AS LT WHERE LT.Id = @id;', 
    N'@id int', 
    @id = 1;
GO
-- Show compilation counter again
SELECT
    DOPC.[object_name],
    DOPC.cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters AS DOPC
WHERE
    DOPC.counter_name = N'SQL Compilations/sec'
```

Run that code several times. On the first time though, many compilations are reported as expected. On the second time, no compilations are reported, unless `optimize for ad hoc workloads` is enabled (so only a *Compiled Plan Stub* is cached). On the third time, no compilations are reported in any case, since any stub is promoted to a fully cached ad hoc plan.

Remove the `DECLARE @TC` statement to see that the `sys.sp_executesql` statement is never cached without it, regardless of the number of times it is executed.

View the associated plan cache entries with:

```
-- Show cached plans
SELECT
    DECP.refcounts,
    DECP.usecounts,
    DECP.size_in_bytes,
    DECP.cacheobjtype,
    DECP.objtype,
    DECP.plan_handle,
    DECP.parent_plan_handle,
    DEST.[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS DECP
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(DECP.plan_handle) AS DEST
WHERE 
    DEST.[text] LIKE N'%sp_executesql%'
    AND DEST.[text] NOT LIKE N'%dm_exec_cached_plans%';
```

Related Q & A: [Do triggers compile each time?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/175073/1192)

Answer (score 11):

You can approximate what you see in Performance Monitor and Activity Monitor for `SQL Compilations/sec` and `Batch Requests/sec`, while running some batches in separate query window as a test, as detailed below.

Query Window 1:

```
DECLARE @t1 datetime;
DECLARE @t2 datetime;
DECLARE @CompVal1 int;
DECLARE @CompVal2 int;
DECLARE @ReCompVal1 int;
DECLARE @ReCompVal2 int;
DECLARE @BatchVal1 int;
DECLARE @BatchVal2 int;
DECLARE @ElapsedMS decimal(10,2);

SELECT @t1 = GETDATE()
    , @CompVal1 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'SQL Compilations/sec                                                                                                            '
        )
    , @ReCompVal1 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'SQL Re-Compilations/sec                                                                                                         '
        )
    , @BatchVal1 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec                                                                                                              '
        );

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000';

SELECT @t2 = GETDATE()
    , @CompVal2 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'SQL Compilations/sec                                                                                                            '
        )
    , @ReCompVal2 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'SQL Re-Compilations/sec                                                                                                         '
        )
    , @BatchVal2 = (
        SELECT spi.cntr_value
        FROM sys.sysperfinfo spi
        WHERE spi.counter_name = 'Batch Requests/sec                                                                                                              '
        );

SET @ElapsedMS = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @t1, @t2);
SELECT  ElapsedTimeMS = @ElapsedMS
    , [SQL Compilations/sec] = (@CompVal2 - @CompVal1) / @ElapsedMS * 1000 
    , [SQL Recompilations/sec] = (@ReCompVal2 - @ReCompVal1) / @ElapsedMS * 1000
    , [Batch Requests/sec] = (@BatchVal2 - @BatchVal1) / @ElapsedMS * 1000;
```

In Query Window 2, run the following while the above code is running.  The code simply executes 100 T-SQL batches:

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) o.name FROM sys.objects o;';
GO 100
```

If you switch back to Query Window 1 you'll see something like this:

```
╔═══════════════╦══════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║ ElapsedTimeMS ║ SQL Compilations/sec ║ SQL Recompilations/sec ║ Batch Requests/sec ║
╠═══════════════╬══════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║      10020.00 ║       10.07984031000 ║          0.00000000000 ║     10.07984031000 ║
╚═══════════════╩══════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

If we look at this query:

```
SELECT dest.text
    , deqs.execution_count
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats deqs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.plan_handle) dest
WHERE dest.text LIKE 'SELECT TOP(1)%'
```

We can confirm there were 100 executions of the test query.

In the results above, you can see we're getting compilations *each time* the `sp_executesql` statement executes.  The plan for that is certainly being cached, yet we see a compilation for it; what gives?

The [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql#remarks) say this about `sp_executesql`:

> sp_executesql has the same behavior as EXECUTE with regard to batches, the scope of names, and database context. The Transact-SQL statement or batch in the sp_executesql @stmt parameter is not compiled until the sp_executesql statement is executed. The contents of @stmt are then compiled and executed as an execution plan separate from the execution plan of the batch that called sp_executesql.

So, `sp_executesql` *itself* is being compiled each time it runs, even if the plan for the command text is already in the plan cache.  @PaulWhite shows in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202178/10832) that most calls to sp_executesql are not, in fact, cached.